# ServiceM8 api new line character in address field

Tags: api, newline

I'm hoping one of the ServiceM8 devs can help me. I need to insert a new line character into the job address field when I create a job via the Rest API endpoint job.json
I have tried using \n but can't figure out the syntax required to escape this properly in the json request body. I just get /n appearing in the job address!
Do you have any examples of how to do this? I have combed through the api reference documentation at developer.servicem8.com
Thanks! Anne

Answer (score 0):

Solution- I used PHP_EOL instead of \n